# CSS & Javascript - border animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have the border animation on the profile photo on this link: https://demo.templateflip.com/creative-cv/

Here's the link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/he1w7z2s/

My fiddle link looks a little different, but what I want is the wave-like animation on the border of the photo `id=about-profile-image`. How can I achieve this using jQuery and CSS?

```css
.about-content-center {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 880px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#about-profile-image {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
}
.about-profile-banner {
    background: url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/img3.n-ix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/16152229/Data-Science-Outsourcing-BLOG-banner-1920-Copy-1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 550px;
    position: relative;
}
.about-content-center {
}
.about-h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
     <!-- CoreUI CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
           <!-- jQuery 3.3.1 -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
<div class="about-profile-banner row align-items-center justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="about-content-center">
        <div class="cc-profile-image">
            <a href="#"><img id="about-profile-image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png" alt="Image"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="about-author">Eric Kim</div>
        <p class="about-author-subtitle text-white">something</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary aos-init aos-animate" href="#" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-anchor="data-aos-anchor">Download CV</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the photo in the fiddle is 404. please update the fiddle.

Comment: try using box-shadow or a pseudo element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `css animation` using `z-index:-1` and `z-index:0`

```css
.about-content-center {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 880px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    padding-top: 0;
}
#about-profile-image {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
}
.about-profile-banner {
    background: url('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/img3.n-ix.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/16152229/Data-Science-Outsourcing-BLOG-banner-1920-Copy-1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 550px;
    position: relative;
}
.about-content-center {
}
.about-h2 {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rounded{
0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0.6, 0.6);transform:scale(0.6, 0.6);opacity:0.0}
50%{opacity:1.0}
100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1, 1);transform:scale(1, 1);opacity:0.0}
}

@keyframes rounded{
0%{-webkit-transform:scale(0.6, 0.6);transform:scale(0.6, 0.6);opacity:0.0}
50%{opacity:1.0}
100%{-webkit-transform:scale(1, 1);transform:scale(1, 1);opacity:0.0}
}
.cc-profile-image a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cc-profile-image a:before {
    content: "";
    border: 15px solid rgba(55,140,63,0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: rounded 1.6s ease-out;
    animation: rounded 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    opacity: 0.0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!-- CoreUI CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
           <!-- jQuery 3.3.1 -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
<div class="about-profile-banner row align-items-center justify-content-center" align="center">
    <div class="about-content-center">
        <div class="cc-profile-image">
            <a href="#"><img id="about-profile-image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png" alt="Image"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="about-author">Eric Kim</div>
        <p class="about-author-subtitle text-white">something</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary aos-init aos-animate" href="#" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-anchor="data-aos-anchor">Download CV</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EricKim Welcome Mate

Answer (score 0):

please try add more this css

```css
.cc-profile-image > a {
  position: relative;
}

.cc-profile-image > a:before {
      content: "";
    border: 15px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 1.6s ease-out;
    animation: pulsate 1.6s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    opacity: 0.0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.cc-profile-image img {
      position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 15px solid transparent;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  opacity: 0.0
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1.0
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 0.0
 }
}

@keyframes pulsate {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6, 0.6);
  opacity: 0.0
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 1.0
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
  opacity: 0.0
 }
}
```